# Why does my SDL program crash in ig11icd64.dll?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have a C++ SDL/OpenGL program which runs for about 20 minutes and then crashes inside `ig11icd64.dll`. The error message from Visual Studio is

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFC4A163E4 (ig11icd64.dll) in memleak.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000001F582020000.

When the program runs, I notice that the `Private (KB)` column in Resource Monitor increases steadily up to around 39,000. However, the Visual Studio memory diagnostic tool shows a flat line at 48.7 MB the almost the entire time.
[image: Visual Studio and Resource Monitor]

My program is fairly simple.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include "wrappers/sdl_context.h"

bool process_events(SDL_Window* window) {
    SDL_Event sdl_event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdl_event)) {
        if (sdl_event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            return true;
        }
        if (sdl_event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT &&
            sdl_event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE &&
            sdl_event.window.windowID == SDL_GetWindowID(window)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    wrappers::SdlContext sdl_context("Memleak!!!!",
                                     /*width=*/100,
                                     /*height=*/100);

    if (sdl_context.status_ != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (gladLoadGL() == 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize OpenGL loader!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        done = process_events(sdl_context.window_);

        int display_w, display_h;
        SDL_GetWindowSize(sdl_context.window_, &display_w, &display_h);
        glViewport(0, 0, display_w, display_h);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(sdl_context.window_);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

where `wrappers::SdlContext` is a simple RAII wrapping.

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>

namespace wrappers {

int sdl_init(const char* title,
             const int width,
             const int height,
             SDL_Window** window,
             SDL_GLContext* gl_context) {
    const int result = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return result;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, 0);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK,
                        SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);
    const SDL_WindowFlags window_flags = (SDL_WindowFlags)(
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    *window = SDL_CreateWindow(title,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               width,
                               height,
                               window_flags);
    *gl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(*window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(*window, *gl_context);
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);  // Enable vsync

    return 0;
}

void sdl_cleanup(SDL_Window** window, SDL_GLContext* gl_context) {
    if (*gl_context) {
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(*gl_context);
        *gl_context = nullptr;
    }
    if (*window) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(*window);
        *window = nullptr;
    }
    SDL_Quit();
}

// RAII wrapper for sdl_init and sdl_cleanup
class SdlContext {
   public:
    // non-copyable
    SdlContext(const SdlContext&) = delete;
    SdlContext& operator=(const SdlContext&) = delete;

    // Calls sdl_init, saving results into window_ and gl_context_
    SdlContext(const char* title, const int width, const int height);

    // Calls sdl_cleanup with &window_ and &gl_context_
    ~SdlContext();

    int status_ = 0;
    SDL_Window* window_ = nullptr;
    SDL_GLContext gl_context_ = nullptr;
};

SdlContext::SdlContext(const char* title, const int width, const int height) {
    status_ = sdl_init(title, width, height, &window_, &gl_context_);
};

SdlContext::~SdlContext() { sdl_cleanup(&window_, &gl_context_); }

}  // namespace wrappers
```

My SDL vesion info:

```
#define SDL_MAJOR_VERSION   2
#define SDL_MINOR_VERSION   0
#define SDL_PATCHLEVEL      10
```

Here is a picture of the call stack at the time of the crash.
[image: call stack]

Comment: Could you show a stacktrace at the moment of crash? Any particular reason why it was called "memleak" in the first place? Does adding `glFlush` change anything?

Comment: I called it memleak because of the effect I was seeing in the resource monitor (that private kb steadily goes up until the crash). As I recall, `glFlush` did not change anything. I'm running it again and it will be about 20 minutes before the program crashes and I can get the stacktrace.

Comment: I had my friend run the program on his computer, and he ran it fine for about an hour, with no memory increase. He has an nvidia card, while I have Intel Iris Plus Graphics, so I think it may have something to do with that.

Comment: @keltar The program crashed at 18 minutes and 11 seconds. I added a screenshot of the stack trace but it seems like some information is missing.

Comment: Trace is complete, it just from different (presumably driver-spawned) thread. I don't think inspecting your `main` thread will reveal anything useful here. Looks like a driver bug to me. I'm not sure what you describe can be called a memory leak yet as it don't seem to extend its virtual memory at all; it *may* be how driver supposed to operate, but having a crash probably isn't. Any driver updates available?

Comment: According to the Intel Graphics Command Center, I'm using the latest driver 25.20.100.7101

Thanks for looking over my issue. Because of your comments I am more confident that this is a driver issue or maybe an issue inside SDL.